# funcion ganancia javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo esta actividad donde debia completar para "Quiero saber en cuántos meses hubo ganancia, es decir, que el saldo fue mayor a cero".

Yo hice esto:

```js
function cantidadDeMesesConGanancia(unPeriodo) {
  let cantidad = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < unPeriodo.length; i++) {
    let mes = unPeriodo[i];
        cantidad = cantidad + mes;
  }
  return cantidad;
}

console.log(cantidadDeMesesConGanancia(1));
```

Pero me da este error:

- La función cantidadDeMesesConGanancia([0, 3, -1, 5]) debe retornar 2
- La función cantidadDeMesesConGanancia([10, -10, 2, 100]) debe retornar 3

Para chequear que meses tuvieron ganacia necesitasa usar el condicional if
Solo tenia que agregar partes, to agregue esto:

```
let cantidad = 0;
unPeriodo.length
```

y esto nomás, lo otro ya estaba escrito

```
let mes = unPeriodo[i];
            cantidad = cantidad + mes;
```

Necesito ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hubiera o hubiese hecho así:

```js
function cantidadDeMesesConGanancia(unPeriodo) {
  let contador = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < unPeriodo.length; i++) {
    let mes = unPeriodo[i];
       if (mes>0) contador++;
  }
  return contador;
}

console.log(cantidadDeMesesConGanancia([10, -10, 2, 100]));
```

Por que tu andabas sumando las cantidades de cada mes al acumulador y asi no consigues el numero de meses si no la cantidad total de ganancias.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Voy a probar así

Comment: Y si necesito que devuelva un array para saber los saldos de los meses que hubo ganancia . Como lo tendria que modificar

Answer (score 0):

Casi está listo solo falta validar que el valor de mes sea mayor a cero para agregarlo  a la cantidad de meses con ganancia.

```js
function cantidadDeMesesConGanancia(unPeriodo) {
  let cantidad = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < unPeriodo.length; i++) {
    let mes = unPeriodo[i];
       // si valor de mes es mayor a cero sumar 1 a la cantidad de meses 
       // con ganancia
        if(mes > 0)
            cantidad++;
    }
  return cantidad;
}

console.log(cantidadDeMesesConGanancia([1,2,-2]));
```